# webkitSpeechRecognition of a recorded video

Tags: speech-recognition

Can i use webkitSpeechRecognition to get text of the uploaded video.

But on the client side as blob.
So user uploads a video on client side, video is not sent anywhere but text is displayed on the textarea.

note: with pure javascript like webkitSpeechRecognition / SpeechRecognition.